# Microsoft Sync Framework, windows mobile device -> WCF -> sql server, possible?

Tags: synchronization, compact-framework, microsoft-sync-framework

I have downloaded from the sync framework webpage an example demonstrating synchronization process between sql ce and sql server through wcf service.

I've wanted to create windows mobile application accessing wcf service on desktop machine.
Is it possible such scenerio?

1. Are there dedicated Microsoft.Services assemblies for compact framework?

Here is my wcf contract interface:

```
public interface IRelationalSyncContract
{
  void Initialize(string scopeName, string hostName);
  void BeginSession(SyncProviderPosition position);
  SyncBatchParameters GetKnowledge();
  GetChangesParameters GetChanges(uint batchSize, SyncKnowledge destinationKnowledge);
  SyncSessionStatistics ApplyChanges(ConflictResolutionPolicy resolutionPolicy, ChangeBatch sourceChanges, object changeData);
  bool HasUploadedBatchFile(string batchFileid, string remotePeerId);
  void UploadBatchFile(string batchFileid, byte[] batchFile, string remotePeerId);
  byte[] DownloadBatchFile(string batchFileId);
  void EndSession();
  void Cleanup();
}
```

I am getting errors that: 
The type 'System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

How to workaround the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sample you downloaded is for the newer collaboration/peer-to-peer providers.

SQLCeSyncProvider is not supported on Windows Mobile Devices.

have a look at using the older SQLCeClientSyncProvider instead, see: [Walkthrough: Creating an Occasionally Connected Smart Device Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488004%28v=vs.90%29)

Comment: well, so I don't understand the reason to use synchronization with sqlce db on the desktop ... Why are there examples demonstrating such mechanisms, when sql ce database is rather lying on smart device? or maybe sqlcesyncporovder is available on windows phone?

Comment: windows phone or windows mobile? those are completely different from a platform perspective...so which one are you using? SQLCe is a perfectly fine database for desktop, even on a webapp...